# Infragistics: How do I Dynamically add data and use ForceDirectedGraphDiagramLayout?

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics

I have a diagram which is bound to an `ObservableCollection` of nodes and an `ObservableCollection` of connections. When the nodes and connections are hard coded into these lists the diagram displays them fine. However, when the node and connection values are added to the lists later on in the program all of the nodes are placed on top of one another at the center of the window. It seems in this scenario the `ForceDirectedGraphDiagramLayout` is not working the way I thought it would. My question is, how can I dynamically add data to a diagram and have the diagram be in `ForceDirectedGraphDiagramLayout`?

Here is my grid:

```
<Grid Background="White">
    <ig:XamDiagram x:Name="Diagram"
                   OptionsPaneVisibility="Visible" 
                   NavigationPaneVisibility="Visible" 
                   DefaultDragInteraction="Pan">
        <ig:XamDiagram.NodeDefinitions>
            <ig:NodeDefinition TargetType="{x:Type models:EntityType}" 
                               KeyMemberPath="Name"
                               ConnectionPointsMemberPath="EntityPoints" >
                <ig:NodeDefinition.NodeStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ig:DiagramNode" >
                        <Setter Property="DisplayTemplate" Value="{StaticResource NodeTemplate}"/>
                        <Setter Property="ShapeType" Value="None" />
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content.FillColor, Converter={StaticResource con}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="140" />
                    </Style>
                </ig:NodeDefinition.NodeStyle>
            </ig:NodeDefinition>
        </ig:XamDiagram.NodeDefinitions>
        <ig:XamDiagram.ConnectionDefinitions>
            <ig:ConnectionSourceDefinition TargetType="{x:Type models:Association}" 
                                           StartNodeKeyMemberPath="End1Name" 
                                           EndNodeKeyMemberPath="End2Name"
                                           StartNodeConnectionPointNameMemberPath="PointFromName"
                                           EndNodeConnectionPointNameMemberPath="PointToName">
                <ig:ConnectionSourceDefinition.ConnectionStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ig:DiagramConnection">
                        <Setter Property="StartCapType" Value="None"/>
                        <Setter Property="EndCapType" Value="FilledArrow"/>
                        <Setter Property="DisplayTemplate" >
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ig:ConnectionSourceDefinition.ConnectionStyle>
            </ig:ConnectionSourceDefinition>
        </ig:XamDiagram.ConnectionDefinitions>
        <ig:XamDiagram.Layout>
            <ig:ForceDirectedGraphDiagramLayout Buffer="200" />
        </ig:XamDiagram.Layout>
    </ig:XamDiagram>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
    private CurrentData currentData = CurrentData.GetInstance();

    private ObservableCollection<EntityType> Nodes { get; set; }
    private ObservableCollection<Association> Associations { get; set; }

    public MyDiagram()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Nodes = currentData.GetNodes();
        Associations = currentData.GetAssociations();

        Diagram.ItemsSource = Nodes;
        Diagram.ConnectionsSource = Associations;
    }

    void OnLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       Diagram.ScaleToFit();
   }
```

`GetNodes()` and `GetAssociations()` return the respective `ObservableCollections`. When the objects in these collections are hard coded in before the program runs, the diagram positioning works perfectly. When objects are added to the lists while the program is already running, all of the nodes are placed on top of one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by moving the data binding from the code-behind constructor to the `OnLoad()` function.

The code behind now looks like this:

```
private CurrentData currentData = CurrentData.GetInstance();

private ObservableCollection<EntityType> Nodes { get; set; }
private ObservableCollection<Association> Associations { get; set; }

public MyDiagram()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

void OnLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Nodes = currentData.GetNodes();
    Associations = currentData.GetAssociations();

    Diagram.ItemsSource = Nodes;
    Diagram.ConnectionsSource = Associations;
    Diagram.ScaleToFit();
}
```